# /tmp directory full

Tags: partitioning, mount

I am running some program on my ubuntu server.
The program got stopped between saying that no space left on device. I checked df -h command. It gave me following result:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs            13G  195M   13G   2% /run
/dev/sda2       101G   42G   54G  44% /
tmpfs            63G  344K   63G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda4       142G  121G   14G  90% /home
/dev/sda3       9.1G  8.6G     0 100% /tmp
/dev/sdb1       7.3T  7.2T  106G  99% /mnt/storage
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs            13G   16K   13G   1% /run/user/131
tmpfs            13G   56K   13G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Then I cleaned /tmp directory and ran the program. But it has given same error.

Please help me solving this error.

Thanks

Comment: It seems your program is writing a lot to `/tmp`. What program is it? What are you doing with it? Would it be possible to use your program in a way, that makes it write less to `/tmp`? Can you increase the size of the partition, where you mount `/tmp`, `/dev/sda3`?

Comment: It is a script which i am using for analysing a dataset of 8.6Gb size. I tried below command                                                                                               sudo mount -o remount,size=20G /tmp                                                                                      but it has given following error : mount: /tmp not mounted or bad option

Comment: Can *you* modify the script? In that case, is it necessary to write temporary files (to `/tmp`)?

Comment: I can't modify script. Because these temporary files are necessary for further steps. Can you suggest any way to increase the /tmp size? I tried but gave error.

Comment: It seems you have mounted `/tmp` in a rather small partition, `/dev/sda3`. Can you modify the parttition table so that the size of `/dev/sda3` can increase, for example to 20 GiB? An alternative is to have `/tmp` inside the root partition (and move the space, that is now occupied by `/dev/sda3` to the root partition, `/dev/sda2`).

Comment: Please notice that modifying the partition table is very risky. So you must **backup everything, that you cannot afford to lose before you start on this adventure**.

Comment: how to modify partition? and how to move the space from /dev/sda3 to /dev/sda2?

Comment: You must boot from another drive, for example an Ubuntu desktop live drive (or if the computer is old, a Lubuntu or Xubuntu desktop live drive (USB pendrive or DVD disk). Then you can run `gparted` to do the editing of the partition table. You can find tutorials about `gparted` via the internet. If the computer does not work with graphical programs, you can get some linux repair live system, that works in text mode, but it is more difficult to use compared to `gparted`.

Comment: You are welcome and good luck :-)

Comment: Why not just take out fstab /tmp entry and let /tmp goes to / ?  All partitions have hi usage so I don't see the point to increase tmp, it just make system harder to use.  You can still modify partition but I think it's best to remove tmp and expand root.